# Why does my ice cream leave a waxy texture on the roof of my mouth?

Tags: ice-cream

I made a batch of ice cream using the following as the base:
1 pint cream,
1 cup milk,
4 egg yolks,
½ cup sugar,
2 tsp vanilla extract

I simmered that until just boiling and then cooled it for a few hours before finishing it up in my ice cream maker for 20min.

I've used this base a few times and add different fruit and spices based on what I want to make.

The problem I'm having is the ice cream leaves a waxy coating on the roof of my mouth. It still tastes great, but the coating is unpleasant. Should I use a different recipe to start with? Am I doing something wrong when I make it?

Comment: the first thing you are doing incorrect is "simmered just until boiling". the critical temperature for custards is somewhere between 83 and 86 degrees C. above that, yolks cook and set. you don't see bubble building in a custard until it's too late.

Comment: Check out this question: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/5400/2001  The answers apply here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try heating the cream and milk to just below a simmer. Right before adding the milk mixture to the yolks whisk the sugar, vanilla, and eggs together. Pour the hot milk mixture into eggs very slowly. It's best to strain it through a fine strainer. If you use vanilla bean make sure to add it after straining it. Let cool a little before putting it into the fridge. It should be cold before making the ice cream. It's not necessary to fully temper ice cream base like crème anglaise.

Comment: If you have a thermometer, use it: Shoot for a temperature between 77–79°C (170–175°F).  Do not let it reach or exceed 80°C (176°F).  If you are using a vanilla bean, I also like to scrape the seeds and reserve for after straining (as @Adam noted), however, I furthermore put the empty pod in the cream and milk as it simmers.

Comment: Oops!  I didn't see @rumtscho's comment above.  He beat me to the punch!

Answer (score 4):

Your fat content is too high.... cream can be as high as 40%. Milk is 3%.... 40 + 40 + 3 = 83 / 3 is 27.6% milk fat. Ice cream should never be above 16%. It should be more of an even ratio of milk to cream.